# Самый простой способ очистить List<T> от дубликатов по конкретной проперти

Tags: c#, list

например

```
List<Student> StudentsGroup = new List<Student>();

StudentsGroup.add(new Student(){Name="Vasia", Surname="Andrienko"});
StudentsGroup.add(new Student(){Name="Vasia", Surname="Potapenko"});
StudentsGroup.add(new Student(){Name="Fedia", Surname="Matsenko"});
StudentsGroup.add(new Student(){Name="Kolia", Surname="Mischenknko"});
StudentsGroup.add(new Student(){Name="Vasilisa", Surname="Vynnychenko"});
StudentsGroup.add(new Student(){Name="Vasilisa", Surname="Onoprienko"});
```

после очистки по Name должно выдать только следующие данные

```
{Name="Vasia", Surname="Andrienko"}//иль второго студента
{Name="Fedia", Surname="Matsenko"}
{Name="Kolia", Surname="Mischenknko"}
{Name="Vasilisa", Surname="Vynnychenko"}//иль второго студента
```

Comment: поставить MoreLinq и вызвать DistinctBy

Comment: @vitidev , ставить отдельную библиотеку в проэкт для того, что можно сделать своим 1м методом -- это как-то по-костыльному.
Да я лучше вручную метод криво напишу. :)

Comment: @vitidev, можно и обычным Distinct, передав ему IComparer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Без использования сторонних библиотек

```
StudentsGroup = StudentsGroup.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

Взято с [англоязычного SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993172/remove-objects-with-a-duplicate-property-from-list)

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Немного правок и заработало. Правки внес и сюда.

Comment: @Andrew, убрал ToList() - этим стоит пользоваться очень избирательно

Comment: @Artem_Flotsky ToList() там нужен т.к. результат селекта -- IEnumerable и без него результат не будет присвоен. Добавил назад. :)

Comment: @Andrew, с присвоением да, согласен. Не хотелось бы, чтобы те, кто придет сюда с таким же вопросом, восприняли, будто ToList() нужно использовать где только возможно =)

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант, воспользоваться перегрузкой [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb338049(v=vs.100).aspx), принимающей вторым параметром `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Например:

```
class StudentComparer : IEqualityComparer<Student>
{
    // Students are equal if their names are equal.
    public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the Student's properties are equal.
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(Student student)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(student, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        return student.Name == null ? 0 : student.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
IEnumerable<Student> noduplicates = StudentsGroup.Distinct(new StudentComparer());
```

Comment: А не проще было бы взять `StringComparer` или `EqualityComparer<string>.Default` и делегировать непосредственно сравнение ему?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, неа, по-моему этот код - компия из мсдн с замененным типом

Comment: *наследование* кода - это плохо. Даже если код *наследуется* из msdn.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, кстати, а как сюда можно _StringComparer_ впхнуть? Создавать экземпляр и у него вызывать equals/gethashcode? Но тогда же только вызов `x.Name == y.Name` упростится? вернее заменится на вызов equals = на мой взгляд не сильно большая разница

Comment: `StringComparer` реализует `IEqualityComparer<string>`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так тут же нужен `IEqualityComparer<Student>`

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться перегрузкой метода [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb338049(v=vs.100).aspx), принимающей `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Вместо полной реализации `IEqualityComparer<Student>` можно делегировать все стандартной реализации, оставив себе только обращение к свойству `Name`:

```
class StudentByNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<Student> {
  private readonly IEqualityComparer<string> cmp;

  public StudentByNameComparer(IEqualityComparer<string> cmp) {
    this.cmp = cmp;
  }

  public static StudentByNameComparer Default { get; } 
      = new StudentByNameComparer(EqualityComparer<string>.Default);
      // Также тут можно использовать StringComparer

  public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
      => cmp.Equals(x?.Name, y?.Name);

  public int GetHashCode(Student x)
      => cmp.GetHashCode(x?.Name);
}
```

Пример использования:

```
IEnumerable<Student> noduplicates = StudentsGroup.Distinct(StudentByNameComparer.Default);
```

Comment: никак не привыкну к новым возможностям:)

Answer (score 1):

Если коллекцию формируете вы, и свойство для проверки всегда одно, используйте HashSet для этих целей, и дубликаты просто не добавятся. Не забудьте, что надо будет переопределить GetHashCode для составления хэша только по изменяющемуся свойству

```
class Student 
{
... /// существующий код
     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
          unchecked 
          {
             int hash = 13; // любое простое число
              return 13* Name.GetHashCode();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Ну и зачем его умножать на 13?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, выходящий за рамки текущего.
Вкратце, при хэшировании используется далеко не только умножение, но и деление наряду с логическими операциями. Простые номера дают меньше коллизий, вот и всего.

Comment: Это намёк, что в данном случае этого делать не надо ;) Потому что тут нет вычисления хеша на основе нескольких хешей, а у единственного поля, чей хеш возвращается, обо всём уже позаботились. Умножение его на какое-либо число ничего не улучшает.

Comment: А, ну так вы бы не начинали из-за печки)
Да, конечно. Но просвещение же)