# Выбор уникальных из List<Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Подскажите как реализовать функцию отбора уникальных в

```
 List<Dictionary<string, string>> dataFFile = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>(3000000);
```

критерием отбора должно быть значение елемента с ключем "EDRPOU"  из Dictionary 
насколько я понимаю можно использовать LINQ или станд фк-цию Distinct. но как реализовать не пойму

[image: пример данных]

Comment: приведите пример данных, что и откуда выбирать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Самый простой способ очистить List<T> от дубликатов по конкретной проперти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510535/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-listt-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8)

Comment: пример данных в прикрепленном скриншоте

Comment: По ссылке в предыдущем комментарии можешь увидеть пример для Distinct