# Удаление дубликатов из List<customClass>

Tags: c#

Есть класс

```
        public class Person
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string middleName { get; set; }
        }
```

И есть список

```
List<Person> listPerson = new List<Person>();
```

Как удалить из этого списка дубликаты сравнивая по полю класса `id` ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/510535/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - спасибо! Но вот это уже помогло 'var myDistinctList = listPerson.GroupBy(i => i.id).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();'

Comment: "Но"? Простите, но терпеть не могу, когда пишут такое (особенно когда тратишь несколько часов на написание полноценного ответа, а тебе "НО"), будто я потратил время в пустую ради того, что человек уже сам сделал, всегда в голове "К чему тогда этот вопрос, если не нужен ответ? Удали и дело с концами, ну или напиши ответ, чтоб другие не тратили свое время в пустую.". Короче, думаю понимаете, что не стоит писать "НО") А так, это скорей не для вас ссылка, а для тех, у кого есть "молот", чтоб закрыли как дубликат, а не рьяно рвались писать очередной ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ перегнул

Comment: @Vipz через `.Distinct()`+`IEqualityComparer` по производительности лучше будет. Но если вам скорость без разницы, то без разницы. А еще лучше `IComparable` реализовать.

Comment: @aepot Ваше право считать это по-своему. Я лишь высказал свое мнение на тот счет, что "Но вот это уже помогло" (другими словами: Спасибо что написали, но я уже решил эту задачу так ..., вы зря потратили свое время") конкретно для меня, ну, немного обидно чтоль. В этом вопросе еще ладно, просто ссылка, но вот когда пишешь ответ по несколько часов, а в итоге "спасибо, я уже решил сам", вот тогда немного подкипает) Не люблю делать что-либо в пустоту, а на ру.SO увы, часто такое происходит. Так что, не считаю, что "перегнул", скорей "намекнул".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прошу прощения за то что задел. Я просто хотел сказать. что в туже секунду нарвался на решение которое тоже помогло. Спасибо и извините.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ еще хуже, когда вообще 0 реакции на ответ, у меня примерно 10% ответов в пустоту. Люди приходят, задают вопрос и уходят никак не реагируя ни на ответ ни на вопросы о полезности не отвечая. Что поделать, удаляю ответы как бесполезные. Но и вам советую так болезненно к этому не относиться, и не высказываться, кто-то может так же болезненно выдать встречную реакцию и спровоцировать конфликт, люди разные бывают. В конце концов, ответ пишется не только для автора, а еще для себя и для сообщества.

Comment: @Vipz Да ничего, как и сказал выше, за ссылку не жалко. Просто в будущем знайте, что тот человек, который хотябы дал вам полезный комментарий - потратил на это свое время, а когда он узнает, что это время он мог и не тратить, человек сам решил все, а вопрос просто висит так, открытый, сами понимаете. Так что, просто без "НО")

Comment: @aepot По этой причине я перестал отвечать многим новичкам, ибо в 80% это ответ в пустоту. Я думаю заметили, что моих ответов на SO практически нет в последнее время, ибо хз, устал чтоль от такого. `для себя и для сообщества` - для себя, хм, ну мне давно SO не дает ничего ценного, блокнотиков и тестовых проектов и без SO хватает, а для сообщества, хм, для кого? Для тех, кто здесь уже сидит много лет и все это видел по сто раз, или для учащихся, которые не могут даже погуглить? Как-то спорное утверждение, но спорить, пожалуй, на эту тему не буду, ибо не место, да и желания нету.